# How to match two cells in different sheets in Google Sheet using QUERY function?

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-query, google-query-language

I have a sheet with two tabs:

Tab1: The first tab contains data in three columns named A, B and C

Tab2: The second tab contains data in three columns named A, B and C. It also includes two cells which I'm going to use conditions. I called them  OpenTime in cell D2 and CloseTime in cell D3.

Goal: I am trying to use query function to search columns in Tab1 and check if their conditions are true, return the value. 
These are three conditions: 
 1. Open Time > (June 30, 2019 5:00 PM)
 2. Close Time < (June 30, 2019 6:00 PM)
 3. C (Value in column C of Tab1) equals to C2 in Tab2 (Column C row 1 in Tab 2) 
This is what I wrote:

```
=query(Tab1!$A:$C,"select $B where $A> timestamp '"& text(D2,"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")&"'" & "AND $A < timestamp '"&text(D3,"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")&"'" & " AND $C Like '"&C2&"'",0)
```

If I apply the above query in Tab1, it works, However, when I paste it in the second Tab (Tab2) it returns an error. 
What am I doing wrong?

Here is the error:

> Unable to parse query string for Function QUERY parameter 2:
>   PARSE_ERROR: Encountered "  "$ "" at line 1, column
>   8. Was expecting one of: "true" ... "false" ... "date" ... "timeofday" ... "datetime" ... "timestamp" ... "min" ... "max" ... "avg" ...
>   "count" ... "sum" ... "no_values" ... "no_format" ... "is" ... "null"
>   ... "year" ... "month" ... "day" ... "hour" ... "minute" ... "second"
>   ... "millisecond" ... "with" ... "contains" ... "starts" ... "ends"
>   ... "matches" ... "like" ... "now" ... "dateDiff" ... "quarter" ...
>   "lower" ... "upper" ... "dayOfWeek" ... "toDate" ...  ...
>    ...  ...  ...
>    ... "(" ... "*" ... "-" ...

Update:
[Link to the spreadsheet:](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1XxDELrNbHmwvFCwD2PiyrcCCLAfdLtM-cS_JcOSmy84/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: @player0 I've added the link to spreadsheet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

correct syntax should be:

```
=IF(IFERROR(QUERY(LiveAttendanceForm!$A:$C,
 "select B 
  where A > timestamp '"&TEXT(D$1, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")&"'
    and A < timestamp '"&TEXT(D$2, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")&"'
    and C = "&$C4, 0))=$A4, TRUE)
```

[image: 0]

Comment: Thanks. It is exactly the same as what I've wrote, however, it doesn't work. Please look at my shared spreadsheet.

Comment: Thanks. It worked. Would you please edit your answer and explain the last sentence. I can't understand why there is only one ampersand without single quote in last sentence: I mean here:  "&$C4

Comment: the reason is because C4 contains a number. if it would be text then it would need to be `' "&C4&" ' "` but numbers in QUERY are treated differently. single quotes indicate that "text is coming"